# TF preprocessing: Imputation class for categorical values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

The goal here is to have Imputation layer for both float and categorical values and I DO NOT want to change/preprocess the type of array that is used as imput. The problem is that when reading array from pandas df that includes np.nan I have an array that both have strings and nan which TF interprets as float and have mismatch dtype when trying to create tensor. So I guess I need some kind of conversion layer maybe with Lambda. I'm not sure.

#### ENV and data

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/michhar/2dfd2de0d4f8727f873422c5d959fff5/raw/fa71405126017e6a37bea592440b4bee94bf7b9e/titanic.csv')
```

#### Problematic array:

```
cabin = train['Cabin'].values
```

array([nan, 'C85', nan, 'C123', nan, nan, 'E46', nan, nan, nan, 'G6',
'C103', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'D56', nan,
'A6', nan, nan, nan, 'C23 C25 C27', nan, nan, nan, 'B78', nan, nan,
nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'D33', nan, 'B30', 'C52', nan, nan, nan,
nan, nan, 'B28', 'C83', nan, nan, nan, 'F33', nan, nan, nan, nan,
nan, nan, nan, nan, 'F G73', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'C23 C25 C27' .. ]

#### Imputation layer

```
class Imputation(keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def adapt(self, data_sample):
        
      if data_sample.dtype in ('float32', 'float64'):
          self.means_ = np.nanmean(data_sample, axis=0, keepdims=0)
          print(self.means_)
      if data_sample.dtype == 'object':
          self.mode_ = mode(data_sample, axis=0)[0]
          print(self.mode_)
        
    def call(self, input):

      if input.dtype in ('float32', 'float64'):
        input = tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(input),
                         tf.constant(self.means_, dtype=tf.float32),
                         input)
          
      if input.dtype == tf.string:

        # HERE i need help
        input = tf.where(input == 'NaN',
                         tf.constant(self.mode_, dtype=tf.string),
                         input)
          
      return input
```

#### Example that the layer works for with e.g. integer

```
imputed = Imputation()
imputed.adapt(train['Age'].values)
imputed(train['Age'].values)
```

#### Example that the layer works with preprocessed categorical array (something I don't want to do)

```
imputed = Imputation()
imputed.adapt(train['Cabin'].values)
cabin2 = train['Cabin'].replace(np.nan, 'NaN').values
imputed(cabin2)
```

array([b'C23 C25 C27', b'C85', b'C23 C25 C27', b'C123', b'C23 C25 C27',
b'C23 C25 C27', b'E46', b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27',
b'C23 C25 C27', b'G6', b'C103', b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27',
b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27',
b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27', b'D56',
b'C23 C25 C27', b'A6', b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27',
b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27',
b'C23 C25 C27', b'B78', b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27',
b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27', b'C23 C25 C27', ... ])

#### My problematic case:

```
imputed = Imputation()
imputed.adapt(train['Cabin'].values)
cabin = train['Cabin'].values
imputed(cabin)
```

### Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-ce3b039382a7> in <module>()
      2 imputed.adapt(train['Cabin'].values)
      3 cabin = train['Cabin'].values
----> 4 imputed(cabin)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    931     # Accept NumPy and scalar inputs by converting to Tensors.
    932     if any(isinstance(x, (np.ndarray, float, int)) for x in input_list):
--> 933       inputs = nest.map_structure(_convert_numpy_or_python_types, inputs)
    934       input_list = nest.flatten(inputs)
    935 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    633 
    634   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 635       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    636       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    637 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    633 
    634   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 635       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    636       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    637 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _convert_numpy_or_python_types(x)
   3237 def _convert_numpy_or_python_types(x):
   3238   if isinstance(x, (np.ndarray, float, int)):
-> 3239     return ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(x)
   3240   return x
   3241 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1380       name=name,
   1381       preferred_dtype=dtype_hint,
-> 1382       as_ref=False)
   1383 
   1384 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1497 
   1498     if ret is None:
-> 1499       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1500 
   1501     if ret is NotImplemented:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py in _default_conversion_function(***failed resolving arguments***)
     50 def _default_conversion_function(value, dtype, name, as_ref):
     51   del as_ref  # Unused.
---> 52   return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
     53 
     54 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    262   """
    263   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 264                         allow_broadcast=True)
    265 
    266 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    273       with trace.Trace("tf.constant"):
    274         return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
--> 275     return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    276 
    277   g = ops.get_default_graph()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    298 def _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape):
    299   """Implementation of eager constant."""
--> 300   t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    301   if shape is None:
    302     return t

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     99 
    100 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this because pandas supports different types in one column series and assign "object" dtype to the columns.

If you want more streamline pipeline, try to use tensorflow csv loader **tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset** (its experimental in my experience its slower than pandas read_csv method) this will make tensor compliant dataset.

empty string will be b'', thus you can easily check them in the tf.where, like this

```
 input = tf.where(input == b'',
                  tf.constant(self.mode_, dtype=tf.string),
                  input)
```